# Bitronix transaction getting exception while loading mule

Tags: mule, mule-esb

I just put an entry like this in aboveof flow `<bti:transaction-manager />`

The below exception i got it.
caused by:

> org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Line 12 in XML document from URL [file:/D:/mule-standalone-3.8.1/mule-standalone-3.8.1/apps/inbound3/inbound3.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'bti:transaction-manager'. One of `{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":annotations, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":description, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context":property-placeholder, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":ref, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":global-property, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":configuration, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":notifications, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-extension, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-shared-extension, "http://www
>   .mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-extension, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-agent, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-security-manager, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-transaction-manager, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-shared-transaction-manager, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-connector, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-shared-connector, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-global-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-exception-strategy, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-flow-construct, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":flow, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":sub-flow, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-model, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-interceptor-stack, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-filter, "http://www.mules
>   oft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-transformer, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":processor-chain, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":custom-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-empty-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":invoke, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":set-payload, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-global-intercepting-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":custom-queue-store, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-processing-strategy}' is expected. (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException) (org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added bitronix namespaces in the xml headers? Make sure that you add the below XML namespaces for Bitronix transaction manager to work.

Check more details at https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/using-bitronix-to-manage-transactions
[image]

Comment: If i deployed it in mule standalone server it throw exception. If i run it in Any point studio its working fine.@RamakrishnaN

Comment: Are you using community standalone or enterprise standalone server?

Comment: I down loaded from the below link [link]https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/mule/distributions/mule-standalone/3.8.1/mule-standalone-3.8.1.zip

Comment: Bitronix Transaction Manager is a Mule enterprise feature. You can't run that on the Mule community standalone server.